# Postgresql + Select field name as upper and lowercase mixed

Tags: postgresql

I am using this postgresql code,

```
SELECT   id as DT_RowId , title 
FROM table_name  
ORDER BY  title asc  
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

The results returned like this.

```
        +--------+-----+
        |dt_rowid|title|
        +--------------+
        |  1     |A    |
        |  2     |B    |
        |  3     |C    |
        |  4     |D    |
        |  5     |E    |
        |  6     |F    |
        +--------+-----+
```

But i want results should return like this.

```
        +--------+-----+
        |DT_RowId|title|
        +--------------+
        |  1     |A    |
        |  2     |B    |
        |  3     |C    |
        |  4     |D    |
        |  5     |E    |
        |  6     |F    |
        +--------+-----+
```

Note - DT_RowId field i want same like this(upper and lower case mixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As explained in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) unquoted identifier are folded to lowercase (which violates the SQL standard where unquoted identifiers should be folded to uppercase).

You need to use a quoted identifier in order to preserve the case:

```
SELECT id as "DT_RowId", 
       title 
FROM table_name  
ORDER BY  title asc  
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```